# How to stream on the Web the voice output of a call when dialing using AT command

Tags: at-command

I want to run a live streaming audio website of the call received when I dial the AT command.

How do I do the sound transmission from the terminal to the website?

Comment: Okay, you've tagged a ridiculous amount of stuff here; how much of it is actually used in your solution so far? What have you tried, and how much is done already? Grabbing AT tones should just be a matter of listening to the sounds produced, doing a frequency transform, and hooking the appropriate frequency combinations.

Comment: The voice of the other caller can be heard,  but what I can't figure out,  is to transmit the tones received to a Website,  where people can hear just what the other person is saying

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There exists no AT commands that will make the audio stream available for processing. Audio might be transfered using [I2S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S) or some other mechanism, but never throuh AT commands.